# Maven cannot find symbol, but independent build works

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, avro

I'm writing a Pig UDF, and trying to use Maven to compile it into a jar. The code registers as being fine in Eclipse, but when I go to build it in Maven, I get a cannot find symbol error, shown below. I've checked the method signature for the openReader method, and it matches the classes that I'm passing it, so I'm not really sure what's going wrong with the Maven compilation.

**Dependencies Snippet:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.kosmosfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>kfs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
            <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.FileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.SeekableInput;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

protected String getLastRecord(String location) throws IOException {
  Path path = new Path(location);
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  SeekableInput input = new FsInput(path, config);
  DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
  FileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader = DataFileReader.openReader(input, reader);
  Iterator<GenericRecord> itr = fileReader.iterator(); 

  long initialPosition = input.tell();
  itr.next();
  long newPosition = input.tell();

  input.seek(input.length() - (initialPosition - newPosition));
  return itr.next().get("id").toString();
};
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project newscred-recsys-udfs: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/andrew/Code/recommender/hadoop/newscred_recsys/udfs/java/src/main/java/com/mortardata/newscred/recsys/SqoopAvroLoader.java:[104,64] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method openReader(org.apache.avro.file.SeekableInput,org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord>)
[ERROR] location: class org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the jar for org.apache.avro has a different set of methods than the jar distributed from the Apache website, causing the mismatch.

Comment: seems strange... did you try to use the avro jar from your local maven repo in eclipse ?

Comment: that's how I fixed the issue. Before I was using the one I downloaded from the apache site during development. But when I went to update the maven file, I encountered this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The project should be cleaned. Project -> Clean